# Split zip archive containing folders now contains "corrupt" zip archive

Tags: archiving, 7-zip

I zipped and split two folders with 7zip, so I got File.zip.001 to File.zip.010.

I renamed them to Foo.zip.001 to Foo.zip.010, and if I open them now, they only contain a "Foo.zip" file. Upon extracting this Foo.zip file, I get an invalid archive error.

Is there a way to restore the folder structure inside this zip format?

Comment: How could you have "renamed" four files into ten files?

Comment: uhh, wow, my bad, editing now.. sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the files probably broke the links between them. Rename the files back to File.Zip.001 to File.Zip.010. Then unzip and rezip them with the name you want. If you still have the original files, you could also just zip them again with the new name.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the split archive's parts does not corrupt the contents. As long as the parts are sequentially named you should have no problems extracting either.

I just tested this in fact with 7zip. Created a split archive with parts **test.zip.001 - test.zip.005**, which I was able to extract fine. Renamed to **best.zip.001 - best.zip.005** and it extracted fine. Renamed just the last part to **best.z05** and on extracting, got a single **best.zip** just as you described. Extracting *this* archive threw an invalid archive error, again matching your experience.

If you're using Windows and have file extensions hidden (as they are by default), it's easy to have thought you renamed the files properly but you might have ended up with mixed extensions. Renaming all the parts in the exact same recommended format i.e. **name.zip.001 - name.zip.NNN** should fix this.